# How to run my js Code wothout Node.js in Vs code -I Get Document is not defined When I use DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, browser

After I Node installation I can not use DOm in my Js files and run them (Pic attached).
Doesn´t recognize the document because is running in the server and not in the browser.

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How can I stop using Node, i already unistall it and doesn´t work, I read somewhere i chould press ctrl shift C and doesnt close the node.

What can I do_?

Aclaration : I already run the code somewhere else and work.

I am expecting to run Js DOM in the browser and stop using Node server and i tried to unistall it but stil doesnt work.

Is it possible to run the code in the browser?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Node does not have a document/DOM. If you want to run code in a browser, create an html page, run a local server, and navigate to the html file..

Comment: I was really happy using the terminal and console of Vscode. After I was recommended to download Node, I couldn't use it anymore to Dom. I know Node Cannot run DOM. I want to use it as before and I don't know how.

Comment: Well if you want to use DOM, you are basically stuck with a browser. Not sure what you are doing that requires DOM so hard to give you any advice.